# Fluid Domain -- Resolution Divisions field disabled (grayed) after freeing bake

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a Fluid Domain where I just freed the Bake in order to change the Resolution Divisions field, yet it remains disabled (grayed).  Any thoughts on how to "jiggle" this to get RD enabled?  The cache folder is clean after freeing the bake.

Here is the [image] file with "proprietary" things removed.

[image]

Comment: happens to me sometimes too. Just click in there...you can change it.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, but sorry: tried and could not. Truly disabled.  I added a lightweight blend example file with other objects removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of modular choose "All" and you can change it again.

[image]

Comment: just like blender: "a trick to get around a bug"  ;-) ... All software has bugs, some more than others.  Many thanks for your time @Chris, and BTW I like all your short animation vids on yt

Comment: @james_t  thank you very much!!!